# SQL: Replace Some Strings with other String Values in One Column and Write to Temp Table

Tags: sql, select, case

UPDATE: Followed syntax provided by forum answers ... hit errors

```
SELECT * INTO #df_ERA4_a_temp 
            CASE WHEN [REQMNT] = 'A' THEN 'ANT'   
                 WHEN [REQMNT] = 'A-12' THEN 'A12'
                 WHEN [REQMNT] = 'ADS-B' THEN 'ADSB' 
                 ELSE [REQMNT]
            END  
    FROM #df_ERA4_a
```

Error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 129
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

---

I'm trying to clean up text data in one column of my temp table.  Afterwards, I want to write the table into another temp table.

Below is the code I used ... but I'm getting an error.

```
SELECT * INTO #test_b
        CASE WHEN [COL] = 'A-12' THEN 'Ant'
             WHEN [COL] = 'A-9' THEN 'Alpha'  
             WHEN [COL] = 'AD' THEN 'Aging'
             ELSE WHEN [COL] = 'Art' THEN 'Artwork'     
    FROM #test_a
```

The error I received was: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'

Comment: Too many temp tables :(

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Your query is non-standard SQL

Comment: I edit my answer, if i'm understanding the question correctly, both temp are tables so the new solution should work. If not, please give us more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** If I understand the problem correctly you want to insert values from test a to test b. If so something like this would be better! You can look at this for help : [SELECT INTO TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

```
INSERT INTO #test_b [test_b.columns]
    SELECT [test_a.columns], 
    CASE WHEN [COL] = 'A-12' THEN 'Ant'
        WHEN [COL] = 'A-9' THEN 'Alpha'  
        WHEN [COL] = 'AD' THEN 'Aging'
        WHEN [COL] = 'Art' THEN 'Artwork'
        ELSE 'something'
    END    
FROM #test_a
```

The `ELSE` can't precede a `WHEN`, you just need the `ELSE` , and you need to close the `CASE` with a `END`. You can refer to : [SQL CASE](https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-case/%22SQL%20CASE%22)

```
SELECT * INTO #test_b
    CASE WHEN [COL] = 'A-12' THEN 'Ant'
        WHEN [COL] = 'A-9' THEN 'Alpha'  
        WHEN [COL] = 'AD' THEN 'Aging'
        WHEN [COL] = 'Art' THEN 'Artwork'
        ELSE 'something'
    END
    FROM #test_a
```

Answer (score 0):

There won't be ELSE and When together.. like you did  **ELSE WHEN [COL] = 'Art'**

```
SELECT * INTO #test_b
        CASE WHEN [COL] = 'A-12' THEN 'Ant'
             WHEN [COL] = 'A-9' THEN 'Alpha'  
             WHEN [COL] = 'AD' THEN 'Aging'
             WHEN [COL] = 'Art' THEN 'Artwork'  
             ELSE 'Some Default value'    -- or don't add ELSE if not required
        END
    FROM #test_a
```

Here is a tutorial on using [CASE in SQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp)

Comment: Missing the `END` to close the `CASE`

Comment: There is an `END` missing after the `ELSE` block.

Answer (score 0):

Write the INTO "#test_b" before the "FROM #test_a" And End before that